# node-red: add a modal dialog on api response

Tags: jquery, node.js, node-red

I need some help with Node Red flow editor. I modified the Export nodes to Clipboard modal dialog and added a button after "Export to clipboard". On clicking the button I make an external API call, which works fine and gets a response back from the server. The code to make an API call is written in /api/editor/code.js file as below:

```
const { flows } = redNodes.getFlows();
axios.post(externalUrl, flows)
    .then((response) => {
        // nice little modal dialog on response
        res.status(200).send(response.data.message);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log('error', error.message);
    });
```

I want to display the information I get from the API call on a modal dialog inside Node Red application. How do I achieve that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Node-RED uses jQuery UI, so you could create your own [jQuery Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) with whatever content you want. There are many examples of using that api available - I won't repeat them here.
2. Node-RED provides the `RED.notify` api for the drop-down notifications. You can use that to display the result.

At its most simple, you can call:

```
RED.notify("This is my message");
```

and that message will appear for a default period of 5 seconds.

If you want to make it stick until the user clicks a button, you can do something like:

```
var myNotification = RED.notify("This is the message to display",{
        modal: true,
        fixed: true,
        buttons: [
            {
                text: "cancel",
                click: function(e) {
                    myNotification.close();
                }
            },
            {
                text: "okay",
                class:"primary",
                click: function(e) {
                    myNotification.close();
                }
            }
        ]
    });
```